# What complications are there if I switch Mysql to MariaDB? Any Drush issues?

Tags: 7, drush, database

I have a heavy *Mysql* drupal 7 site and I was thinking about switching *Mysql* over to *Mariadb*, but I wasn't sure what issues I would run into. From what I'm reading *Mariadb* seems to be just a drop in replacement for *Mysql* and there doesn't seem much to fiddle with. I was wondering if *Mariadb* would affect drush commands?

Comment: ok i got my server techs to switch over to mariadb. so far haven't noticed anything major yet, but from our experience we had alot of issues while doing an upgrade. Since we were on an older version of cpanel, we had to first upgrade cpanel to the latest version, then update PHP, then update Mysql, then switch back the PHP version to 5.2 to maintain compatibility issues. Now we install MariaDB. It took 13 hours for this transition! A pricey lesson I must say, thinking it was only going to take less than an hour. Test on staging first! hopefully this helped someone, +rep if it did! thanks!

Comment: There are several issues to think about. Debian unix_socket default is one of it. I wonder that these issues are not discussed much. I assume many have their work flows and still stick with MySQL, thats why it is not well documented. Let me link to a new posted issue to collect some thoughts on this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242634/mariadb-unix-socket-causes-access-issues-under-debian-drush-cant-login

Comment: @nilsun Quite the opposite, pretty much everyone uses MariaDB these days. Here's Pantheon's canonical article on why they use it for hundreds of thousands of Drupal sites, for example: https://pantheon.io/blog/using-mariadb-mysql-replacement. The issues you're talking about seem to be niche, that's probably why you can't find much discussion about them

Comment: @Clive Thank you. I partly agree. But you count big players. A small dev team is another situation. If there is nobody in the team with the expertise to correlate Debian packaging behaviour and MariaDB philosophies you CAN (not must) encounter some small challenges from changes. And especially when you use Third party software, which has no error messaging prepared for such scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to chime in on this (albeit months late)...
Have set up many Drupal sites in the past, decided to do things "better" this time and had MariaDB installed.

Everything works wonderfully (faster, cleaner, etc) with Drupal 7 EXCEPT for backup/restore :/
Always have to go directly into the db (whether through PHPMyAdmin, Heidi, or command line) and copy/export all of the tables.

Other than that, which there could be a number of reasons for happening, I highly recommend MariaDB. Less server resources used, D7 is much faster, etc etc.

Comment: But this thread is not about the pro and cons of MariaDB and how good it is. It is about well thought questions regarding production work flow changes to discuss with Drush. And there are several.

Answer (score 8):

As you say, Maria DB is a drop-in, completely transparent replacement for MySQL. Its releases coincide with the same major/minor version of MySQL so it's pretty much always in tandem as far as features are concerned. It reads the standard MySQL binary data files, uses the standard systen my.cnf, and even has a drop-in replacement for InnoDB.

The idea is that as far as your application is concerned it thinks it's connecting to a MySQL server. It uses MySQL drivers, issues full MySQL statements, and receives responses exactly as the MySQL server would send. Your app(s) won't know the difference.

I've been using Maria for a while now for Drupal sites (also using Drush extensively) and haven't had a single problem to date. If you're running *nix upgrading is just a two minute job.

Comment: awesome. just what i needed to know. thx!

Comment: one other thing is i occasionally do sql queries via the terminal. what would be the equivalent of doing a msyqldump? or drush sql-query 'select * from users'

Comment: I _think_ mysqldump uses /usr/bin/mysql (or equivalent) internally, and since Maria symlinks that path to its own implementation you wouldn't need to make any changes, just continue using mysqldump as normal. I'd imagine the same applies to Drush. It might be worth checking up on that though to be certain

Comment: Google for "MariaDB Debian unix_socket access issues" ... There are still things to discuss and to document.

Comment: @nilsun I haven't had experience of those issues - I've been running Drupal 7 on dozens (probably hundreds) of MariaDB-backed servers for years without problems. Pantheon run their entire Drupal/drush infrastructure on MariaDB, and I think Acquia do too. You might just be using the wrong version/configuration, or have a niche requirement that results in strange behaviour. All the agency developers I know also use MariaDB, wouldn't dream of using plain old MySQL, so it wouldn't appear to be a common problem (in my experience at least)

Comment: @Clive thanks for chiming in! Good to know. TBH, I was secretly hoping of some contra positions to the picture I paint, because that also means: there is hope for a solution on the horizon :) But still, there were already others reporting it. My guess: something has changed in latest Debian. Read my other thread to understand the loop of small issues you will stick in, if it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues to worry about. The Debian `unix_socket` *root access issue* is only one of them. I wonder that these issues are not discussed much. I assume many have their work flows and still stick with [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL). That's why many of these issues are not well documented.

Related: [MariaDB unix_socket causes access issues under Debian - Drush can't login](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/242634) (A new post started to collect thoughts on this.)